# UITableViewCell not modifying it's properties

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uitableview

I have a subclass of UITableViewCell with a xib that I want to use as my table view cell. I need to modify the cell's properties on a cell by cell basis. Here is my code. The NSLog reveals that the properties are changed correctly, but when I run the app, the usernameLabel stays the same as the placeholder in the xib file. I'm grateful for any help and happy holidays.

```
  -(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:      (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";

  //  ActivityCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
LiveCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    // Load the top-level objects from the custom cell XIB.
    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"LiveCell" owner:self options:nil];
    // Grab a pointer to the first object (presumably the custom cell, as that's all the XIB should contain).
    cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
}
if (dataLoaded == YES) {
    cell.usernameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];

    NSLog(@"Data Cell Loaded");
    PFObject *liveObject = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.usernameLabel.text= liveObject[@"Name"];
    NSLog(@"Name Label: %@", cell.usernameLabel.text);

    return cell;
}
else {
    return cell;
}
```

}

Comment: `cell.usernameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init]` is unnessery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this code:

```
cell.usernameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
NSLog(@"Data Cell Loaded");
PFObject *liveObject = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.usernameLabel.text= liveObject[@"Name"];
NSLog(@"Name Label: %@", cell.usernameLabel.text);
return cell;
```

You made a label and set its text, but so what? You never put it into the interface of the cell. So the label comes into existence, its text is set, and it then vanishes in a puff of smoke.

If the cell already *has* a `usernameLabel` in its interface, then it is wrong to replace it with this new one that is not in the interface. If it doesn't already have a `usernameLabel`, then you need to put this one in the interface. Either way, this code is silly.

Comment: How would I fix it? I want the usernameLabel to be on each cell, but the text needs to change.

Comment: Is there already a `usernameLabel` in the cell? Does `usernameLabel` already point to it through an outlet? If so, then just delete that first line. All that line does is _destroy_ the outlet. You had this all set up in the xib file and then you are wrecking it with that one line.

Comment: Do you understand how objects are instantiated? You are instantiating this label _twice_ - first by loading it from the xib (good), then by replacing it with a brand-new label that you create in code (bad).

Comment: Might want to read this section of my explanation of where instances come from: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch05.html#_how_instances_are_created